# replace command gives "invalid syntax" error

Tags: replace, syntax, unique, stata

So my command goes like this:

```
replace tradeflowcodepart = tradeflowcodepart[_n-1] + 1 if tradeflowcodepart = tradeflowcodepart[_n-1] & partnername = partnername[_n-1]
```

It keeps giving me an `invalid syntax` error.

`tradeflowcodepart` is a binary variable and the other one after the `if` is a string.

My eventual goal is to make every observation unique so that I can `merge` it with another table (where I plan to do a similar exercise to make every observation unique). So if the previous `tradeflowcodepart` and `partnername` are the same as in the current observation, then I want to add a number to the `tradeflowcodepart` to make the observation unique.

Comment: You need `==` not `=` when you test for equality. See `help operators`.

Comment: Your variable won't remain binary for long if you keep incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

In Stata after the `if` operator always comes a logical expression, which `evaluates` to TRUE or FALSE. If TRUE, the part before `if` (the command itself) is executed, otherwise aborted. Given it's a logical expression, Stata uses `==` sign, instead of `=` Correctly specified, your command would be:

```
replace tradeflowcodepart = tradeflowcodepart[_n-1] + 1 if tradeflowcodepart == tradeflowcodepart[_n-1] & partnername == partnername[_n-1]
```

Comment: Aborted is quite the wrong word here. Assuming the command is legal, then the point is that observations are treated differently according to whether the `if` condition is true or false. It's not even always the case that observations for which the `if` condition is false are ignored, as `generate y = 42 if x > 1` results in missing values for `y` when the condition is false.